# Vim visual mode to system clipboard?

Tags: vim, osx, copy-paste

Using the vim text editor, I am looking for a method to copy content highlighted in visual mode to the system clipboard (i.e. I would then be able to `Ctr-v` that content say in a browser window).

Is there a standard way to copy content directly to the system clipboard?  If not is there a suited hack to enable it for Mac OS 10.7.3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your VIM was built with the clipboard feature enabled, then you select your text in visual mode, and then type <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.

To paste from the clipboard, do <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: @Kurt The text register `"*` is special, it places the selected text into the X CLIPBOARD.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Each time I press `"*` I get a bell and then `y`/`p` perform their independently mapped actions.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with OS X, from what I have gather it does not properly map the `X CLIPBOARD` as mentioned by Keith. (it seems rather unsuited to even call OS X Unix anymore!)

Comment: For OSX [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing) was rather helpful.  Basically there is a command `pbcopy` and `pbpast` which you able to call for say the current line `. !pbcopy` or if you don't want the current line cut `.w !pbcopy`.

Comment: Right, the `"*` register is only available where VIM was built with the right settings. It might be that OS X can't do that, but I can't check as I don't have it.

Comment: @ams No worries, you answered the question I asked and it lead me to the `pbcopy` command which I will likely map to something more convenient along with an undo command `Ctr-u` as it deletes the content which it copies, but in any case your help is appreciated!